# libgdx-Actions create stuttering

Tags: java, libgdx, action, game-physics

I try to improve the movement of my figures but i dont find the real reason why they stutter a bit. I am moving them with an [`SequenceAction`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/SequenceAction.html) containing an [`MoveToAction`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/actions/MoveToAction.html) and an `RunnableAction` that does reset the `moveDone` flag so there can be started a new move.

The game itself is gridbased so if a move is done the squence starts a move to the next grid depending on the direction. So here is how it looks like:

**note that this is inside of the Act of the figure**

```
....//some more here
if (checkNextMove(Status.LEFT)) //check if the position is valid
{
    status = Status.LEFT; //change enum status
    move(Status.LEFT); // calls the move
    screen.map.mapArray[(int) mapPos.x][(int) mapPos.y] = Config.EMPTYPOSITION;
    screen.map.mapArray[(int) (mapPos.x - 1)][(int) mapPos.y] = Config.CHARSTATE;
    mapPos.x--;
    moveDone = false;
}
//... same for the up down right and so on.
//at the end of this checking the updating of the actor:
// methode from the absctract to change sprites
updateSprite(delta);
super.act(delta); // so the actions work
//end of act
```

And here is the move Method that does add the Actions

```
protected void move(Status direction)
{
    // delete all old actions if there are some left.
    clearActions();
    moveAction.setDuration(speed);
    //restart all actions to they can used again
    sequence.restart();
    switch (direction)
    {
    case LEFT:
        moveAction.setPosition(getX() - Config.TILE_SIZE, getY());
        addAction(sequence);
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        moveAction.setPosition(getX() + Config.TILE_SIZE, getY());
        addAction(sequence);
        break;
    case UP:
        moveAction.setPosition(getX(), getY() + Config.TILE_SIZE);
        addAction(sequence);
        break;
    case DOWN:
        moveAction.setPosition(getX(), getY() - Config.TILE_SIZE);
        addAction(sequence);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

The figures dont really move smothy.

- Anyone does see a misstake or isnt it possible to let them move smothy like this?
- It always stutter a bit if a new move is started. So i think this might not work good. Is there a differnt approach to move them exactly from one Grid to an nother? (Tried it myself with movementspeed * delta time but this does not work exactly and i struggeled around and used the Actionmodel)
- it seems to make troubles with the one Frame where it does not move for example.

Here is an mp4 Video of the stuttering:
[stuttering.mp4](http://www.sulco.de/stuttering.mp4)

*just to mention, the camera movement is just fine. it's smothy but the figure stutters as you can see i hope*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so i solved it myself. It has nothing todo with changing sequences around. It has something todo with the updatefrequency  of the `act()` of the figures. The `MoveToAction` interpolates between the 2 points given by time. So if the last update, updates the `MoveToAction` by "to much time" it would need to go over the 100% of the action. So it would move to far but the action does not do this it set the final position and thats what it should do.  Thats why it does not look fluent.

[image: Discription of the real problem]

So how to solve this issue?

By decreasing the updatetime the "to far movement" decreases too because the steplength is getting smaller. So i need to increase the updatespeed above the 60fps. Luckily i got an thread for my updating of the figures and positions and so on. `GameLogicThread`. This ran on 60fps too. So i solved the stuttering by increasing it's frequence. up to around 210fps at the moment so the "overstep" is minimal. You can't even notice it.

To Show how my thread works:

```
public class GameLogicThread extends Thread
{
    private GameScreen m_screen;
    private boolean m_runing;
    private long m_timeBegin;
    private long m_timeDiff;
    private long m_sleepTime;
    private final static float FRAMERATE = 210f;

    public GameLogicThread(GameScreen screen)
    {
        m_screen = screen;
        setName("GameLogic");
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        m_runing = true;
        Logger.log("Started");
        while (m_runing)
        {
            m_timeBegin = TimeUtils.millis();
            // hanlde events
            m_screen.m_main.handler.processEvents();
            synchronized (m_screen.figureStage)
            {
                // now figures
                if (m_screen.m_status == GameStatus.GAME)
                {
                    m_screen.character.myAct(1f / GameLogicThread.FRAMERATE);// and here it is ;)
                    m_screen.figureStage.act(1f / GameLogicThread.FRAMERATE);
                }
            }
            m_timeDiff = TimeUtils.millis() - m_timeBegin;
            m_sleepTime = (long) (1f / GameLogicThread.FRAMERATE * 1000f - m_timeDiff);
            if (m_sleepTime > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(m_sleepTime);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    Logger.error("Couldn't sleep " + e.getStackTrace());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Logger.error("we are to slow! " + m_sleepTime);
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopThread()
    {
        m_runing = false;
        boolean retry = true;
        while (retry)
        {
            try
            {
                this.join();
                retry = false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use your `moveAction` each move, you should call `moveAction.restart()` to reset the counter inside it:

```
// delete all old actions if there are some left.
clearActions();
sequence.reset(); // clear sequence
// add movementspeed. Note it can change!
moveAction.restart();
moveAction.setDuration(speed);
```

**UPDATE**:

Now issue occurs, because you call `restart` of `SequenceAction` after `clearActions()`. If your `clearActions()` removes all actions from `SequenceAction` then `restart` will be called for empty `SequenceAction`. So, do this instead:

```
//restart all actions to they can used again
sequence.restart();
// delete all old actions if there are some left.
clearActions();
moveAction.setDuration(speed);
```

Comment: well they dont move wrong. they stutter when a new move startes. But still added the restart but it does not change the stuttering.

Comment: @BennX, Whay do you mean with stuttering? Could you please provide example images/gif/video?

Comment: It's hard to create a video from it. It seems that the figure compleatly stops and than moves on if you run into one direction. I think its cause because the moveto moves it to the spot and than it moves on with a new moveto. But the interpolation of both actions should be the same. Just updated the code to a cleaner version. and update the question

Comment: added the requested video.

Comment: @BennX, added one more possible reason for this issue.

Comment: This actually increased the stuttering. And this is sure like that because i restart them while they are still inside of the Actor. if i clear the actor and than restart it has no effect to the actor ...

Comment: @BennX, could you please provide all related code? May be I don't see the whole picture. Also, you should try `new SequenceAction()` every move instead of reseting, it could help.

Comment: If it would be that simple to solve i wouldnt have asked it in Stackoverflow. And you never use the `new` operator in games if its not needed! Imagin. All mein monsters move liket his so up to 600 entities every second they create 3 new sequences. Thats 1800 objects a second for movement that are not needed.